# Calculate data usage UDP in Android

Tags: android, udp, android-trafficstats

How to calculate data usage only in UDP in Android devices? 
I use TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() to get TCP but I need only UDP

Comment: I need calculate traffic in device, not send a packet and wait to receive a response. Thanks

Comment: How to calculate traffic only UDP? Any answer?